# Why does Teams start transmitting my voice only if I speak for at least few seconds?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-teams

Why does Teams start transmitting my voice only if I speak for at least few seconds?

The situation is like this. When I'm in a meeting or on voice call I need to be talking at least for a few seconds without pause before others begin to hear my voice. This happens even if I have my microphone enabled/unmuted all the time.

When they do start to hear my voice it is not as it would lag but first few seconds are simply missing.

If I do a test call my whole speech gets repeated entirely.

Does anybody have a clue of why this would be happening and how could I fix this.

Comment: Is there any background noise?

Comment: Are you using a headset ?

Comment: Yes I'm using USB based headset

Comment: No there is no background noise